# XAMPPでcakephp導入したい。「intlが見つからない」と出てくる。

Tags: macos, cakephp, composer, xampp

OS 10.12.6でXAMPP7.1.10 / PHP 7.1.10を使い、cakePHP3を導入しようとしています。
「PHPフレームワーク　CakePHP3入門」の本の通りに環境構築を進めています。
まず、XAMPPの中のファイルにある「php.ini」の文頭にテキストエディタで「extension=php_intl.so」と加えました。
「ターミナルから環境変数PATHへの追加」も行い、XAMPPにあるPHPが実行されるようにしました。
そしてcomposerをダウンロードして、composer.pharを使ってcakephpをインストールする段階で、「intlが見つからない」と出てきて詰まっています。
このようなトラブルはMacでは起きやすいとのことで、本に書いてある通り、XcodeとCommand Line Toolをインストールしたのち、HomeBrewをインストールし、intlとautoconfをインストールしましたが、結局うまく行きません。

問題のエラーはこちらです。

Installing cakephp/app (3.5.0)

Installing cakephp/app (3.5.0): Loading from cache
Created project in cake3app
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1

cakephp/cakephp 3.5.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
cakephp/cakephp 3.5.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
cakephp/cakephp 3.5.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
cakephp/cakephp 3.5.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
cakephp/cakephp 3.5.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.5.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.5.3, 3.5.4].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
You can also run php --ini inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

ご回答のほど、何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/98089

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP3.xをmariadb/mysqlで動かすために必要なものは、例えばLinux版は以下になります。
apache類
・httpd
・mod_rewrite.so
php類
・php
・php-devel
・php-mbstring
・php-pdo
・php-gd
・php-intl
・php-xml
・php-mysql
mariadb/mysql類
・mariadb-server
その他（Composer利用に必要）
・git
・unzip

Xampp版はそれぞれdllで同伴されていますが、いくつかがデフォルトで読み込まれません。
以下のように設定ファイルに記述されているか確認し、適宜修正してください。
また、Composerも用意してあげましょう。

xampp\apache\conf\http.conf
・LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

xampp\php\php.ini
・extension=php_intl.dll
・extension=php_mbstring.dll

Composer-Setup.exe

なお、プログラムの組み方がいい加減だと
ディレクトリ区切り記号問題などが発生するため
開発Xampp：本番Linuxなどの想定はお勧めしません。
本番がLinuxの場合は、
開発もVirtualBoxなどを利用してLinux上に構築することを強くお勧めします。

Answer (score 0):

下記URLが参考になるかもしれません。
https://qiita.com/ysnsyks2/items/176cfddbdf1f79d65a75

上記URLによると

> ->php.intlがはいってない

が原因のようです。
インストールしてみましょう。